# Signal Processing: Windowing signal improves stopband rejection, why?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, windowing

Hello my fellow signal processors!

When I bandstop filter a signal, the stopband rejection is much better after also windowing the signal with a Hanning window. 
The rejection was assessed by looking at the DFT. In Fig. 1 you can clearly see that the frequency contents in the stopband is much lower after windowing.

Does anybody have an idea why that happens? Thank you!

(sorry I can't post pictures apparently, Fig 1 is in a pdf.)

http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~jrichner/effect_of_windowing.pdf
Fig. 1. top: DFT of gaussian white noise. mid: DFT of gaussian white noise, bandstop filtered. bottom: DFT of gaussian white noise, bandstop filtered and windowed

EDIT: I am now pretty sure that the effect we are observing is due to [spectral leakage](http://www.tmworld.com/article/322450-Windowing_Functions_Improve_FFT_Results_Part_I.php). Windowing the bandstop filtered signal with a Hanning window reduces the leakage into the stopband, resulting in a better performance of the filter. Thank you for commenting and reading!

Comment: Good question and excellently asked! I'm having a bit of trouble interpreting the spectra I'm looking at - could you perhaps post the code that generated them? In particular it would be good to know what bandstop filter you are using, and which windowing method.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and respond!  <br/>

1) The bandstop filter is an elliptic IIR filter designed with fdatool.  <br/>

2) A Hanning window was used.  <br/>

Code:
%create hanning window
wind = hanning(1024)';
%create white gaussian noise
x     = randn(1, 1024);
specx = abs(fft(x));

%filter the noise with elliptic bandstop
xf     = filter(bandstop_elliptic_60db, x);
specxf = abs(fft(xf));

%compute DFT of windowed and filtered noise:
specxfw = abs(fft(xf.*wind));

%plotting
[ran out of characters.]

Comment: As you can see, StackOverflow doesn't allow much formatting in comments. Instead of trying to provide substantial information in comments, edit your original question to include everything you just wrote (use the code formatting syntax where appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks, I when I realized, it was already too late to edit. =(

Answer (score 0):

Windowing a time signal corresponds to convolving it in the frequency domain. In your case, you window the the filter output, which has low spectral values around your bandstop frequency. Therefore, when you convolve such a spectrum with your window spectrum the spectral values that are already big gets bigger and values that are smaller gets smaller. Moreover, this works due to the fact that white noise has a flat spectrum, so you do not alter the frequencies other than your bandstop frequency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree with the first sentence. The second sentence I don't understand. Why would this happen? My understanding of windowing is that it amounts to a smoothing in frequency domain. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.